# What does 'mode' mean in and AGOL WebMap operational layer properties?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-online-webmap

I am accessing an Operational Layer in a WebMap and updating some properties. There is a 'mode' property that is set to 1. What does mode mean? and what values will it accept? and what does each value correspond to?

It is not present in other layers so I am wondering what is the difference with this layer that adds the 'mode' property?

Heres how I am accessing the Operational Layer properties.

```
from arcgis import GIS
from arcgis.mapping import WebMap

agol = GIS("home")

wm_item = agol.content.get("***wm_id***")

wm = WebMap(wm_item)

lyr = wm.get_layer(title="Lyr_Name")

print(lyr)
```

Here's a snippet of the properties returned that contains mode.

```
{
  "id": "id",
  "layerType": "ArcGISFeatureLayer",
  "url": "url/of/feature/layer",
  "visibility": true,
  "opacity": 1,
  "mode": 1,
  "title": "Lyr_Name",
  "itemId": "***item_id***",
  "layerDefinition": {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "mode" property is specific to feature layers, relates to how features are retrieved from the server in some web clients, and is documented at:

- https://developers.arcgis.com/web-map-specification/objects/featureLayer/

For example, it [was](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html) a property used in the 3x version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, but is handled automatically in version 4.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks